# How to get the function call parameters passed by user in substrate into txn-pallet?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

Suppose based on user inputs I want to set fee.(not on len , weight of txn) Is that possible to get the data into transaction payment pallet and based on that data I want to set the fee?
Is that possible?
As fee is calculated before the function execution how to get the call parameters into transaction-payment-pallet?

Answer (score 2):

The Transaction Payment Pallet is designed to specifically handle fees based on the Weight and the Length of an extrinsic, but you can always make your own pallet which handles fees in a different way.

The hard part is that, since each pallet is separate and arbitrarily designed, you cannot really create a feature where some specific parameters in the extrinsic input will be used to compute the fee, because you cannot know what those parameters individually mean.

You can design your own trait + macro which implements some feature onto all the extrinsics you want, where you pass in the specific parameter you want, but this will be pretty involved, and also involve the creation of a new fee pallet.

The easier solution, at least for just prototyping, will probably be to remove any of the weight fee included with an extrinsic `Pays::No`, and then use the balance of the user directly to remove some as a signed extension.

Comment: Hi shawn ... Thanks for your input...... let me clear u.....So, if the call is comming from staking pallet and the function called is bond(amount) then I want to set a fee based on amount they wanna bond.... Is there a way to know the amount(passed as a parameter) in txn-payment pallet?? (and for rest of the cases I want to use existing fee structure only.)

Comment: You are better off creating a brand new extrinsic with the same functionality, and your own custom fee structure into the logic of that extrinsic. It is not really practical to override a generic fee pallet for a single scenario.